# Open Office: How to automate address in letter to post to envelope?

Tags: openoffice-writer, envelope

Say I have a letter with an address in the body. How can I make it so an envelope is linked to the document and automatically feeds in the address. Ideally, I'd love to know how to take a list of addresses and names as variables and create letters and envelopes for the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a mail merge.  There is a lot of documentation for this on the web, such as: http://blog.worldlabel.com/mail-merge-in-openofficeorg-everything-you-need-to-know